# Images moved to left on Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Recently, my company migrated to Windows  7 operating system.

I was using the following master file in Visual Studio 2010 on my Windows XP machine and everything was working fine, now that I migrated the following code to Windows 7 and same Visual Studio 2010, all the images below are moved to left. I can adjust them, but I am curious why all the images are moved to left, I am using the same monitor and Visual Studio 2010 version is same.

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.master.cs" Inherits="Masters_Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../App_Themes/NG/style.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <style type="text/css">   
          div ,
           div img { display:block } 
            .fl  
              {
                  float:left; 
                  margin-left:15%;
                  background-color:#8e2826;
                  width:68.1%;
                  margin-right:18%;
                  text-align:center;
              }

              .f2
              {
                  float:left; 
                  margin-left:15%;
                  background-color:#e5e0dd;
                  width:68.1%;
                  margin-right:18%;
                  text-align:center;


              }
              .f3
              {
                    float:left; 
                  margin-left:15%;
                  background-color:#d4cfcd;
                  width:68.1%;
                  margin-right:18%;
                  text-align:center;




              }

                .style1
        {
            color: #8e2826;
        }

      </style> 
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >



           <div style="margin-left:15%; background-color:#343434; width: 68.1%; margin-right:18%; ">  

                     <asp:Image ID="imgIS" ImageUrl="~/images/improved_LOGO.jpg" runat="server" />




        </div>

         <div class="fl" >


         <asp:Image ID="imgTop" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/m_banner_top.jpg" />

         </div>

  <div class="f2">
   <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/m_banner_btm_5.jpg" />


  </div>

  <div class="f3" ></div>


    <div class="f3">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>



            <div style="margin-left:15%; margin-right:18%; width: 68.1%; background-color:#8e2826; text-align:center">

             <asp:Image ID="banner" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/b_banner_calibri.jpg"/>





       </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've got `float:left;` set in `.fl` and `.f2`, both set to `div`s which contain images. Your `DOCTYPE` also seems to be incomplete: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "`

Comment: this one the reasons because i'm against the use of ASP.net and Visual Studio - people that doesn't know HTML begings to "code" without follow any standart. Not personal offense.

Comment: If you want to align them to the center of the page, you have to specify in you CSS:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align them to the center of the page, add the following lines to you CSS:

```
width://fixed width;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
```